# Trouble with with code Python 3

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, arraylist

I am very new to python and I'm still learning, I am having trouble trying to get this in my array:

- Winner of each Event
- The House with the best average
- The house with the most number of wins

With this code:

To get event names:

```
Flag = True
while Flag:
    try:
        e = str(input("Enter Event names [Type XXX to stop]: "))
        if e == 'XXX' or e == 'xxx':
            Flag = False
        else:
            event.append(e)
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter a word, Thanks")
print()
```

To get house name:

```
Flag = True
while Flag:
    try:
        h = str(input("Eneter House names [Type XXX to stop]: "))
        if h == 'XXX' or h == 'xxx':
            Flag = False
        else:
            total = total + 1
            house.append(h)
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter a word, Thanks")
print()
```

For getting the points of events and houses

```
for i in (event):
    for j in (house):
        Flag = True
        while Flag:
            try:
                sevent = int(input("Enter %s's house for %s score: "%(j, i)))
                if sevent < 0:
                    print("Enter a number above 0, Thanks")
                else:
                    Flag = False
            except ValueError:
                print("Please enter a number above, Thanks")

        if j not in scores:
            scores[j] = []
        scores[j].append(sevent)
        score.append(sevent)
```

I have got it too print overall winner and the total score for each event but I don't know how to get the winner of each event, the house with the best average and the house with the most number of wins.

To get the Overall winner and total score for each event:

```
for house, score in sorted(scores.items(), key=lambda x: sum(x[1]),reverse=True):
    print ("House %s's Total Score: %i"%(house, sum(score)))
print(scores)
print("The Overall Winner is", max(scores, key=lambda h: sum(scores[h])))
print()
```

An example of the Output is:

```
House House 1's Total Score: 80House House 3's Total Score: 70
House House 2's Total Score: 40
The Overall Winner is House 1
```

The array of the example as follows:

```
{'House 1': [20, 60], 'House 2': [30, 10], 'House 3': [40, 30]}
```

Thanks for any help, I really do appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

First off, consider the way you have constructed the dictionary `score`:

- the score for `event[0]` is in in `score[house_name][0]`,
- the score for `event[1]` is in in `score[house_name][1]`,
- ...
- the score for `event[last_event_index]` is in in `score[house_name][last_event_index]`.

Therefore, to get the winner for each event, you first have to enumerate all events:

```
for event_index, event_name in enumerate(event):
    ...
```

If you're not familiar with [enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/functions.html#enumerate): it will associate a zero-based index to each event name. So that if you have `event = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']`, `enumerate(event)` will yield the following pairs:

- `(0, 'A')`
- `(1, 'B')`
- `(2, 'C')`
- `(3, 'D')`

Now you can iterate over all houses and extract their score for the specific event:

```
for event_index, event_name in enumerate(event):
    for house_name, house_scores in scores.items():
        print('House %s scored %d in event %s' % (
            house_name,
            house_scores[event_index],
            event_name,
        ))
```

In order to get the best scoring house, we can place each score in a list and sort it:

```
for event_index, event_name in enumerate(event):
    event_scores = []
    for house_name, house_scores in scores.items():
        house_event_score = house_scores[event_index]
        event_scores.append((house_event_score, house_name))
    # This will sort 'event_scores' from the lowest score
    # to the highest.
    event_scores.sort()
    # The winner (with the highest score) is the last element
    # of the list, i.e. the element with index -1.
    winner_score, winner_name = event_Scores[-1]
    print('%s has won %s with score %d' % ((
        winner_name,
        event_name,
        winner_score,
    ))
```

Comment: I may sound stupid, I'm sorry for this. where should I put this code seems it pretty new to me.

Comment: @ReganKelly: you should place that code together with your other calls to `print()` (I mean: `print(scores)`, `print("The Overall Winner is", ...)`, ...).

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you I tried doing this by but it didn't work
print("The Overall Winner is", max(scores, key=lambda h: sum(scores[h])),for event_index, event_name in enumerate(event):
          for house_name, house_scores in scores.items():
          print('House %s scored %d in event %s' % (house_name,house_scores[event_index],event_name,)))

Comment: @ReganKelly: can you post the traceback?

Comment: 'print("The Overall Winner is", max(scores, key=lambda h: sum(scores[h])),for event_index, event_name in enumerate(event):
          for house_name, house_scores in scores.items():
          print('House %s scored %d in event %s' % (house_name,house_scores[event_index],event_name,)))' where shows for event_index that is where the error is

Comment: Mh... did you really write `print(...),for event_index, ...`? I mean: did you really put a comma between the `print()` and the `for`? If that is the case, beware that `for` needs to be on its own line. Otherwise, please post the exact error message you are getting.

Comment: This picture shows what the output of your code, it is not really what I wanted because I want it to print out house winner of each event.
https://gyazo.com/5bbab8e206d13d79bc8af4568ead9829

Comment: Thanks for that, would it be possible for you to do the house with the most number of wins. I would really appreciate it. Thanks